# Is there any way to implement unscrollable header for UISplitViewController RootViewController?

Tags: iphone, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

What it did in RootviewController of UISplitViewController -

```
UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.frame.size.width, 0)];  
    [searchBar setPlaceholder:@"Search within application"];
    searchBar.delegate = self; 
    [searchBar sizeToFit]; 
    searchBar.tintColor=[[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:212.00/255 green:236.00/255 blue:256.00/255 alpha:1.0 ];

    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar;  
    [searchBar release];
```

It's working fine but when we scroll tableview searchbar is also moving with tableview rows.

I want to implement searchbar which will always visible to the user.

*I can try with SearchDisplayController but in UISplitViewController we are not getting .xib file for RootViewController.*

Please help me out on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add your search bar to the navigation controller's navigation bar. Here are the steps:

1. change the frame of the navBar by adding the height of the search bar to its `frame.origin.height`.
2. add the search bar as a subview
3. change the class of the controller's `view` to `UIView` (assuming it is now a table view) and add a new subview `UITableView`, adjusting the frame according to your search bar height.
4. reconnect the new tableView with the controller (`delegate`, `datasource`, `tableView` outlet).

This worked for me.